# How to exit array listing in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

I am on Linux(Ubuntu) and using `pry` to debug ruby code, but can't figure out how to stop array listing (shown in image). I tried using ctrl+D, ESC, pressing Enter and almost every other character basically. I can't type anything.

I guess solution is quite simple but can't seem to figure it out.[image]

Comment: Press 'q' to exit that pager

Comment: FYI: by default Pry uses _less_ as its pager, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/less for a list of available commands.

Comment: @Stefan <nitpicking> it uses what is set as default pager in the shell, and the shell uses `less` by default </nitpicking>.

Comment: @mudasobwa oh indeed: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-other-pager-than-less

Comment: Thank you. I was sure that I pressed every button on keyboard. Don't know how I missed q.

Comment: I believe any of these should work (found by running `man less` on my system): `q`, `Q` `:q`, `:Q`, `ZZ`